# How to remove null from serializer.data when return response in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to remove null from serializer.data before return final response to the end users.
Like every order contain some order-items, but i want that orders only which have status 'new' in order-items and and in to_representaion method I only order-items in case of new status and if there is any other status, I don't want that order will be send in response so I don't add anything to it, but when final response send to the user, it contain null for that order. Please help me with that.

Here is my code:

```
def list_order_by_status(request):
order = Order.objects.all()
serializer = ListOrderSerializer(order, many=True, context={"status": request.data['status']})
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is my reponse:

```
0: {…}
1: null
2: {…}
```

Here is my to_representation mehtod:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    serialized_data = super().to_representation(instance)
    order_id = serialized_data.get('order_id')
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(order_id=order_id, status=self.context['status'])
    order_items_serializer = ListOrderItemSerializer(order_items, many=True)
    if order_items_serializer.data:
        serialized_data['order_items'] = order_items_serializer.data
        return serialized_data
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `print(serializer.data)`?

Comment: I already add the response above.

Answer (score 0):

you can just override the `to_representation` function of the serializer for this. And have something like this:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super().to_representation(instance)
    return {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v is not None}
```

Comment: Please see my code again. I have upload my to_representation method.